# KeyError: 'name' in Spotify Web API

Tags: python, python-requests, discord.py, spotify

I'm using spotify's web API to get song information for a discord bot im making. I'm hosting the bot on heroku. im using the tracks option to get the track name and artist name from a songs ID. When the bot is on heroku, it throws the following error:

https://pastebin.com/smqqqDfY

however, when i host the same code on my laptop, it gives no such error. I even separated the spotify code to see if the JSON file has a key named 'name' and it works!

the code is:

```
#pulls the name and artist name from the API and link
def spotifypull(uri):
    r = requests.get(spotify_base.format(id=uri), headers=headers)
    r = r.json() 
    return (r['name']+" "+r['artists'][0]['name'])

#checks if the link is a spotify link(this is from the "request" function)
if query.find("spotify") !=-1:
    uri = query[31:53]
    name = spotifypull(uri)
```

this same code gives the proper output if separated locally

```
import requests

query = "https://open.spotify.com/track/6WkrFOo6SGAjhGMrjIwAD4?si=VDwYLniGQLGmqzUK3RdBow"
uri = query[31:53]

SPOTIFY_ID = "<id>"
SPOTIFY_SECRET = "<secret>"
AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
ytbase = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
auth_response = requests.post(AUTH_URL, {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': SPOTIFY_ID,
    'client_secret': SPOTIFY_SECRET,
})
auth_response_data = auth_response.json()
access_token = auth_response_data['access_token']
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'.format(token=access_token)
}
spotify_base = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/{id}'
r = requests.get(spotify_base.format(id=uri), headers=headers)
r = r.json()
name = r['name']+" "+r['artists'][0]['name']
print(name)
```

output of above:

```
Wasn't Enough CrySpy
```

Any help would be massively appreciated! the full code is [here](https://github.com/AnveshakR/AnnuBot/blob/main/annubot.py) if needed.

edit:
when ran locally,
r.text is https://pastebin.com/sjrW3exW
r.get_status is 200

Comment: Please do not post image of code or error message. If it does not fit use a pastebin.

Comment: @ygorg better now?

Comment: What does the response from the server look like and is there an error code ? Maybe this is more of a server problem than a python KeyError problem ?

Comment: @ygorg the response from the server is in the pastebin link

Comment: I can't find what `r.text()` looks like after `r = requests.get(spotify_base.format(id=uri), headers=headers)` in the pastebin. Also try printing `r.status_code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got the issue, the spotify token was expiring after an hour. Thanks to @ygrorg for the idea.

Edit: Since some max brain mods want me to provide more clarity, Spotify tokens are valid for only an hour, I solved it by calling for a new token everytime a song is played. Alternatively, its only possible that you put the token regeneration commands in an infinite loop and put a delay of 30-45 min at the end of the loop, so you have a fresh token every time.